# HTML validator fails with custom html elements

Tags: html, validation

When i try to [validate](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) an HTML file with custom elements, then it will get errors.

Can anyone explain why?
Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Some app</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div data-wt="hmm">
   <hello-world>Yes!</hello-world>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Then it says that the hello-world element is not valid.
But the custom attributes are valid.

Comment: The Custom Elements spec is in draft so the validator cannot be expected to validate something that is under change and not working in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

While you can invent new attributes (by using `data-...`) you can not just invent new elements - this would make the HTML invalid.

You could register new elements, as [described here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/).

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('hello-world', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});
```

But as this use JavaScript, the validator will still not pass.

Comment: Is it required to register a custom element? I dont see any reason why i should.

Comment: Nevermind, i just found of that it is required to do it. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/introduction-to-custom-elements/#what-about-accessibility